# Difference between derivative at point, and analytic at a point.

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there a difference between a function that has a derivative at point, and a function
that is analytic at a point? If a function is analytic in a bounded region, is the function
bounded?

Answer (score 1):

A function can have a derivative at a point and not be analytic at that point. An example is $f(z)=|z|^2$, which has a derivative only at $z=0$. However, if a function has a derivative at all the points of an open set $D$, then it is analytic at all he points of $D$.

As for the second question, consider $f(z)=1/(1-z)$ on $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$.